# Rails Static Footer Layout

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

_footer.html.erb

```
<footer class="footer">
<small id="footerRight">
  Language Without Limits Powered By <img src="/assets/rails.png" />
</small>



<nav>
  <ul id="footerLinks">
    <li><%= link_to "How It Works", about_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Contact",  contact_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "News",     news_path %></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</footer>
```

css:

```
#footerLinks {
position:relative;
top:22px;
right:15px;
}

#footerRight {
position:relative;
right:-15px;
}
```

Issue can be seen by looking at ninjaspeak.com. When on homepage the footer displays how I want it to look on all pages of the website. When clicking another link, 'How It Works' for example, the footer content collapses in towards the middle of the page. Any ideas on what may be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the home page has malformed/missing HTML, and it's actually the other pages that are rendering properly.

One issue may be commas after the href attributes of your language signup links (a typo in a link_to helper, perhaps?). Either because of this, or in addition to this, there are stray closing div tags.

I'd look more closely at how the home page's source is rendering in the browser to see this happening.

The other pages don't appear to share this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The footer in the sub pages is in the outside div i.e. the

```
<div class="container"> and in the homepage, you don't have a <div class="container">.
```

That is the main reason why the footer appears in the middle in the subpages.